# Angular 7 - Object combination and array

Tags: angular

I have one model Userc (name, phone, email, etc..)
and another model Usercco (the same with one more value coname (company name)

In Userc i have (coid : "the company id")
In DB (firebase) I have only Userc and Company

I tried to merge all Userc and Company.coname to get a list of Userco :

**in the component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.usercService.getAllUserc().then(
      (userc: Userc[]) => {
        this.usercs = userc;

      });

      this.usercco= this.usercService.AddConametoUsercs(this.usercs)
      console.log(this.usercco);

  }
```

**In UsercService (this one Works):**

```
 getAllUserc() {
        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
                firebase.database().ref('userc/').once('value').then(
                    (data: DataSnapshot) => {
                        resolve(data.val());
                    }, (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
```

**And the otherone (Don't works) :**

```
AddConametoUsercs(usercs: Userc[]) {
        var size= usercs.length;
        console.log('Taille : '+size);
        for (let i = 0; i < usercs.length; i++) {
            this.companyService.getCompany(usercs[i].coid).then(
                (company: Company) => {
                    this.company = company;
                    this.usercco[i].coname = this.company.coname;
                }
            );
            this.usercco[i].coid = usercs[i].coid;
            this.usercco[i].usercid = usercs[i].usercid;
            this.usercco[i].usercfname = usercs[i].usercfname;
            this.usercco[i].userclname = usercs[i].userclname;
            this.usercco[i].usercemail = usercs[i].usercemail;
            this.usercco[i].role = usercs[i].role;
        }
        return this.usercco;
    }
```

How can i merge Userc data with Company.coname into Usercco ?

I know that length don't work because it's an Object not an array. Then How to get each Userc[] item ? Without length function.

Thanks for your help ^^d  ((^o^)/)

Comment: Are you getting correct company name inside getCompany() function?

Comment: Yes getcompany works, i use it for a lot of other components.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already taking place in the component.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.usercService.getAllUserc().then(
      (userc: Userc[]) => {
        this.usercs = userc;

      });

      this.usercco= this.usercService.AddConametoUsercs(this.usercs)
      console.log(this.usercco);

  }
```

You are not waiting for the `getAllUserc` promise to resolve before calling the `AddConametoUsercs` method. In the resolve function you are setting the `userc` value, but before that has even resolved you are calling the `AddConametoUsercs` method.

A simple fix for this would be move to the assignment of `usercco` in the promise.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.usercService.getAllUserc().then(
      (userc: Userc[]) => {
        this.usercs = userc;

      });

      this.usercco= this.usercService.AddConametoUsercs(this.usercs)
      console.log(this.usercco);

  }
```

Your `AddConametoUsercs` in the user service suffers from some problems, a big red flag for me was the usage of promises in for loops. And from my understanding you simply want the `Userc` to contain a `companyname` property which so happens to live in a different place in firebase and is fetched through `getCompany`

This can be solved very elegantly using `async-await`, but I urge you to get a better grasp on promises before getting into using `async-await`. Here is the solution with good ol promises though.

**Solution**

First of all, we want to get all the company names for all our users before we do any merging. We will do this by looping through the users, returning their `coid` and calling `getCompany`.

```
// First step
//
AddConametoUsercs(usercs: Userc[]) {
  /** This array will contain all the company ids */
  const companyIds: number[] = usercs.map(userc => userc.coid);
}
```

After that, we want to do something similar to the loop with `Promise.all`. This takes an array of promises as input. In this case it will be an array of promises that `getCompany` returned

```
AddConametoUsercs(usercs: Userc[]) {
  /** This array will contain all the company ids */
  const companyIds: number[] = usercs.map(userc => userc.coid);
  /** This is an array of promises */
  const companyPromises: Promise<Company>[] = companyIds.map( companyId => this.companyService.getCompany(companyId) );

  const usersWithCompanyNamePromise = Promise.all(companyPromises)
    .then( companies => {
      // companies[0] would match the company with the id matching companyIds[0]
      // which corresponds with the first user in usercs (usercs[0])

     /** We want to loop through our companies, and return a user with the 
      * company name
      */
      const usersWithCompanyName = companies.map( (company, index) => {
        /** 
        * This is the magical part, because the companies were fetched in the 
        * same order as the users
        */
        const correspendingUser = usercs[index];

        const userWithCompanyName = {
          // Using the object spread operator to put the user data here
          ...correspendingUser,
          coname: company.name
        }
        // Returning the new structure, which will end up in usersWithCompanyName
        //
        return userWithCompanyName;
      });

      return usersWithCompanyName;
    });

  return usersWithCompanyNamePromise;
}
```

Comment: Oh So Great ! I tried this I got one error on the line                                                Type 'Promise<{}>[]' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Company>[]'.
  Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Company>'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Company': coid, coname, service, address, and 18 more.ts(2322)

Comment: And Userc.coname doesn't exist, Only Usercco.coname exist.

Comment: @BenYsil Did you edit the signature of the method ? Because the object we are returning is not a company object, but merely a user object with the `coname` added.

Comment: getCompany(id: string) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('company/' + id ).once('value').then(
          (data: DataSnapshot) => {
            resolve(data.val());
          }, (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

Comment: 'Userc' + 'Coname' is type 'Usercco'

Comment: @BenYsil then set the type of `userWithCompanyName` to `Usercco`.

Comment: 'const companyPromises: Promise<Company>[] = companyIds.map(companyId => this.companyService.getCompany(companyId));' doesn't works because getCompany() return a promess not a company

Comment: @BenYsil getCompany returns a promise that contains a company, hence the usage of the Promise generic in that way `Promise<Company>` Its also an array of promises hence the `[]` at the end.